# Using filter and sorting in aggrid custom header and custom cell renderer

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I've a custom header as well a custom renderer.  Normally if there is a default header and cell filter and sorting works good with just "sortable: true, filter: 'filterName' " . But this doesn't work once I start working with custom component. Can anyone tell me is there a workaround for this? I'm using angular8.

Comment: Where are you using a custom component? As a header, as a filter or as a cell editor?

Comment: @NamanJain Currently I have a custom header as well a custom component as row renderer...   Need a filter and sort beside header... Thanks for the reply Naman.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/component-header/. The first example here works perfectly. As for sort you have to use `colDef.filterParams`